# How to setup get_head(), get_foot(), and other files like wordpress uses

Tags: php, wordpress, function, constants

I am trying to migrate my site to PHP and use a WP theme on my site with out modifying the theme too much. So my problem is that I want to create a functions.php file like in Wordpress that contains some code that can be called to load the header and footer of my sites theme from each page. Also I want to keep some constants in another file that will be used in my site for loading files from my sub-domains, getting the current year, etc. I have a basic `get_file()` function for loading files from my static content domain, But when I try to run it I get this:

> **Parse error**: syntax error, unexpected **T_FUNCTION** in **/home/s0urc3/public_html/includes/functions.php** on line **4**

Here are the contents of my functions.php and my constants.php:

#### functions.php

```
<?php
include('constants.php')
/*Gets a file from the domain http://files01.s0urc3.ismywebsite.com/*/
function get_file($file)
{
FILE_ROOT + $file
}
get_file(images/bg.jpg)
?>
```

#### constants.php

```
<?php
/* CONSTANTS*/
define(FILE_ROOT, "http://files01.s0urc3.ismywebsite.com/")
define(HOME, "http://s0urc3.ismywebsite.com/")
define(BLOG_HOME, "http://blog.s0urc3.ismywebsite.com/")
define(FORUMS_HOME, "http://forums.s0urc3.ismywebsite.com/")
define(YEAR, getdate(year))
/*define(FILE_ROOT, "http://files01.s0urc3.ismywebsite.com/")*/
?>
```

Any and all help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have virtually no lines free of syntax errors. You will never get anywhere muddling your way forward this way. Find a tutorial and learn PHP before trying to port your code.

#### Specifically:

In PHP, as in other C-style languages, your statements must end with semicolons:

```
// bad; missing semi-colon
include('constants.php')
// good:
include('constants.php');
```

Your uses of [`define`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php) are wrong. The symbol to define must be passed to `define()` as a string before it can be used as a symbol:

```
// bad; FILE_ROOT not yet defined, missing semi-colon
define(FILE_ROOT, "http://files01.s0urc3.ismywebsite.com/")
// good:
define('FILE_ROOT', "http://files01.s0urc3.ismywebsite.com/");
```

[Strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) must be enclosed in either single quotes or double quotes:

```
// bad; missing quotes around string, missing semi-colon
get_file(images/bg.jpg)
// good:
get_file('images/bg.jpg');
```

Values must be explicitly returned from functions via the `return` keyword, and strings are [concatenated](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) using the dot `.` operator:

```
// bad; Perform integer addition, doesn't return, no semi-colon
FILE_ROOT + $file
// good:
return FILE_ROOT . $file;
```

And a note on style: You've commented `get_file` as 'getting a file', which it definitely doesn't do. All it does is return the fully-qualified URL of the relative URL you pass it. Your function names and comments should strive to clearly tell you what they do. In the case of such a short utility function, I'd go for something very short:

```
// Return the fully-qualified URL for the given file
function url_for($file)
{
  return FILE_ROOT . $file
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In PHP most lines end with a semicolon ';' This is what is giving those errors.

```
// should be
include('constants.php');
get_file('images/bg.jpg');
// etc.....
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Syntax makes no sense, look what your function does, it would be the same as just writing:

```
function get_file($file)
{
    "http://files01.s0urc3.ismywebsite.com/" + $file
}
```

Thats not PHP or anything, what exactly is it you want to do? If you want the complete filepath, it would be :

```
function get_file($file)
{
    return FILE_ROOT . $file;
}
// returns: http://files01.s0urc3.ismywebsite.com/images/bg.jpg
```

Comment: Seems it's a mix of javascript and templating code, which isn't really php code

Comment: oops i am more experienced with js html and css than php.

Answer (score 0):

You should have 2 seperate files, **constants** and **functions**

Put data in each accordingly and the simply include them and use

```
require_once 'constants.php';
require_once 'functions.php';
```

within functions the example layout should be like so:

```
function a()
{
    //...
}
function b()
{
    //...
}
function c()
{
    //...
}
```

followed by usages:

```
if(!user_session_active())
{
    location('home');
}
get_file('some_file.ext');
```

Answer (score 0):

1. you forgot semicolons at the end of *every* line where you have to use one. (after the defines, after the include, after the function call...)
2. string concatenation in php works bu using `.`, not `+`